# Alpha channel areas inside and outside of something

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm looking at a photo of a pair of eyeglass frames.  All around the eyeglasses--extending to the four JPEG edges--are pixels consisting of RGB values 251 through 255, depending on where I click with the eyedropper tool on that more or less white background.

On the insides of the eyeglass frames (the two eye portals), the pixel values I want to operate on consist of RGB 190 through 245--where the lenses are.

I want to alpha all of those.  Is there a way to select pixels en masses in a way that's predicated just on RGB value--bearing in mind that a lot of the aforementioned are pixels that are isolated as noncontiguous islands surrounded by pixels of other but only similar RGB values?  If so, how?

Then replace with an alpha channel?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: tagged adobe-photoshop but if you're on OS X Preview.app does this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the Magic Wand tool (shortcut key is <kbd>W</kbd>).

This allows you to select similar areas by adjusting the Tolerance value. I would suggest a starting value of about 20. Use smaller values to select a smaller range of similar RGB values.

As well as adjusting the Tolerance, you can also use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to add to your existing selection.

You can optionally touch up your selection by going into Quick Mask mode (<kbd>Q</kbd>) and using the brush tool (<kbd>B</kbd>).

Depending on what you want to acheive, you can either delete (<kbd>Del</kbd>) the selection to make the area transparent or you can use the selection to create a layer mask to achieve the transparency. (Layer -> Layer Mask - Hide selection)

If this is the background you're dealing with, you'll need to promote it to a layer first. (Right click on the Background in the Layers window and select Layer from Background)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Mike. I may have to follow up with a few other questions but this has gotten me way ahead of where I was. For instance I don't see a Tolerances feature in PS CS4, but if I right click after deploying the Quick Selection Tool, I'm given a mini menu that contains menu option "Color Range..." inside of which there is a "Localized Color Clusters" check box with a Fuzziness slide control.  Is this synonymous with the Tolerance value?

Comment: When the Magic Wand tool is selected you should see the Tolerance field on the Options toolbar beneath the main menu bar. If you don't, go to the Window menu and make sure Options is ticked. To get to the Magic Wand tool in the first place, you may need to left-click and HOLD on the Quick Selection tool button until a sub-menu appears.

Comment: Ahh, thanks.  After you first replied I ended up using the Quick Selection Tool that was enabled by W because I didn't know this.  Still it seems that Quick Selection did a good enough job for the time being, but it's good to know now about how to get to the Magic Wand tool if I need to.

Comment: Everything you said works fantastic.  Thanks.  (At first I just deleted the selection but that didn't alpha it, so I went back and read what you suggested after that and it works great!)  Thanks again, this is all exactly what I needed.